# Delete record with composite primary key in OData

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api2, odata, asp.net-web-api-odata

I have an entity Student. Below is the signature of delete method in ASP.net WebAPI for OData.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Delete([FromODataUri] int key)
```

The Student has composite primary key.
When called from Postman, with

```
http://localhost:52484/Students/1
```

it doesn't hit the Delete method.
But it works with other entity with single primary key.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly prefix param with 'key' for composite key Entity. OData v4

Refer the example below:

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Delete([FromODataUri] int keySudentId, [FromODataUri] int keyClassId)
    {
      //Delete code here
    }
```

OData Url
http://localhost:52484/Student(SudentId=1,ClassId=2)